# How to configure Docker swarm mode on Mesos

Tags: docker, mesos, docker-swarm, marathon

how to configure Docker Swarm mode in Mesos. If I start to google I am getting the old way of doing it. (running the swarm image )

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=qUViQAu2Bw0

if I search further people are saying swarm mode is competitor of Mesos (I may be wrong)

https://blog.bugsnag.com/container-orchestration-with-docker-swarm-mode/

My requirement to run java programs, Node js apps, Angular apps, Kafka, Storm, Spark , Mongo DB, Elastic search on the container.

Please suggest me some good idea to continue to setup my cluster with docker container.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check the [documentation](https://github.com/docker/swarm/blob/master/cluster/mesos/README.md):

> "When using Docker Swarm and Mesos, you use the Docker client to ask the Swarm manager to schedule containers. The Swarm manager then schedules those containers on a Mesos cluster."